# How to change destination range

Tags: vba, excel

How to change `Destination:=Range("A1")` in the loop?

```
Set objWeb = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add( _
Connection:="URL;https://stackoverflow.com/questions/" + i + "/change-range-in-running-macro", _
Destination:=Range("A1"))
```

With **objWeb**

Comment: Could anyone help to show the way to change destination range in the loop?
In the first loop, the destination would be A1. The second loop, the destination is A150.

Comment: If you have a loop, and the loop is relevant to the context of your question, it could be good to include it (see [mcve]). That said, you need to figure out a way to be able to do `Destination:=Range("A" & something))`